# XPath expression returning no results

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ExtractResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ExtractResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sunstein.Services.WebServiceClient.ClientMatter" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:ClientMatterNumber>
                    <a:ClientNumber>00005</a:ClientNumber>
                    <a:MatterNumber>00003</a:MatterNumber>
                </a:ClientMatterNumber>
                <a:ClientMatterNumber>
                    <a:ClientNumber>01234</a:ClientNumber>
                    <a:MatterNumber>00101</a:MatterNumber>
                </a:ClientMatterNumber>
                <a:ClientMatterNumber>
                    <a:ClientNumber>01234</a:ClientNumber>
                    <a:MatterNumber>01234</a:MatterNumber>
                </a:ClientMatterNumber>
            </ExtractResult>
        </ExtractResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to build XPath to ultimately reference one of the `ClientMatterNumber` nodes, but in building it up, I'm having trouble.  For example, this works:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body
```

But this returns no results:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/ExtractResponse
```

What am I missing?  I've tried a number of online XPath testers, including [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), but they all result in the same behavior.

Comment: while experts do not see - `/s:Envelope/s:Body/*[name(.) = 'ExtractResponse']`

Comment: @splash58 -- Can you please clarify your cryptic comment?

Comment: it works in online testers, but i never can to work with namespaces so it maybe not quite correct

Comment: ExtractResponse has an default namespace (no prefix) in xml. but in xpath normally  you have to use an prefix for that. How to register a namespace (with prefix) depend on the (xpath) processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you can't bind the namespace to a prefix for your XPath engine (like wero correctly states in his answer) you can use [`local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) in a predicate to check the name:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/*[local-name() = 'ExtractResponse']
```

You could also use [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-namespace-uri) to make sure you're matching the exact element you're intending to:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/*[local-name()='ExtractResponse' and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']
```

Comment: @wero - Thanks, but your answer is definitely the way to go if the processor supports it.

Answer (score 5):

The element `ExtractResponse` in your document has the namespace uri `http://tempuri.org/`.

Any unprefixed location step in an XPath expression, e.g. the  `ExtractResponse` in your expression, will not have a namespace uri and therefore cannot match an element with an URI.

To fix this you need to declare a namespace mapping (e.g. `x=http://tempuri.org/`), pass that to your XPath engine and modify the expression accordingly (e.g. `/s:Envelope/s:Body/x:ExtractResponse`).

**Note:** The online XPath tester you mentioned is a fine tool but has only limited support for XML namespaces, so you can't successfully run your expression with that tool.

Comment: I don't have control over the XML....it's the result from a WCF service invocation.

Comment: @roryap the XML is fine. You just need to instruct the XPath engine and modify the XPath expression

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm still trying to grasp what's going on here, and the xpath engine I'm using doesn't allow for me to declare namespace mappings unfortunately, so I guess I'm out of luck...?

Comment: @DanielHaley -- Thank you, I'm working my way through that now.  XPath is quite an abstruse topic.

Comment: @roryap - Went ahead and added my comment as an answer. XPath is a little abstruse in the beginning. Having a processor that can't handle default namespaces doesn't help either. :-)

Comment: @DanielHaley -- In fact, this is what I got from the processor :( "namespace-uri: Function not supported."

Comment: @DanielHaley time to change your processor?

Comment: @roryap - Yuck. Try without `namespace-uri()`. It should work then, but you run the risk of matching elements with the same local name and different default namespaces.

Comment: @wero - No my processor is fine lol. roryap might need a new one though ;-)

Comment: @DanielHaley -- Using [IntApp's Integration Builder](http://www.intapp.com/products/information/intapp-integrate) trying to process the response from a web service call.  Their XML tool set is just not sufficient apparently.